# Animation quality is better with matshow() than with imshow(). How to improve it?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, imshow

I displayed an array with matshow and it works fine but now I want to try imshow. The issue is that the quality of imshow is really poor compared to matshow.

How can I fix this ?

**Matshow:**

```
matshow(array)
```

[image: FIG 1]

**Imshow:**

```
plt.imshow(array)
```

[image: FIG 2]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The issue is due to [interpolation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html).

Matplotlib [`matshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.matshow.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.matshow) is a wrapper for [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow), in that it *"sets origin to ‘upper’, ‘interpolation’ to ‘nearest’ and ‘aspect’ to equal."*

So while matshow always uses `interpolation="nearest"`, `imshow` by default has `interpolation=None`. Note that this is different from `interpolation="none"`.

- `interpolation=None` uses the interpolation set in the `image.interpolation` variable from the [matplotlib rc file](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) (which can be different in different matplotlib versions.)
- `interpolation="none"` uses no interpolation, same as `"nearest"`

The safest way to overcome this problem is to specifically set an interpolation method in both calls

```
plt.matshow(array, interpolation="none")
plt.imshow(array, interpolation="none")
```

Comment: Is there a difference between `"none"` and `"nearest"`?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Yes, "For the Agg, ps and pdf backends, interpolation = 'none' works well when a big image is scaled down, while interpolation = 'nearest' works well when a small image is scaled up" from https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html. For other backends, it appears that they are the same ("none" will fall back to "nearest").