# Difference between `plt.imshow()` and `plt.matshow()` for Heatmaps

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, heatmap

I'm working with the following matrix, and I want to creat a heatmap using `Matplotlib`:

```py
a = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1], [4, 4, 4, 4]]
```

I've read the documentation and understand that `plt.imshow()` is a more general function for image display. However, when I use both `plt.imshow(a)` and `plt.matshow(a)` to create a heatmap, the outputs appear identical. In the context of visualizing a matrix as a heatmap, are there any differences between the two functions?

P.S.: code for heatmaps

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.matshow(a) # Or `plt.imshow(a)`
plt.show()
```

Comment: take a look at the accepted answer of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910060/animation-quality-is-better-with-matshow-than-with-imshow-how-to-improve-it#:~:text=Matplotlib%20matshow%20is%20a%20wrapper,from%20interpolation%3D%22none%22%20.   `Matplotlib matshow is a wrapper for imshow, in that it "sets origin to ‘upper’, ‘interpolation’ to ‘nearest’ and ‘aspect’ to equal."`

Answer (score 1):

Both functions are similar to some extent. As you said, plt.imshow() is more generally used. It's not specifically designed for heatmaps but can be adapted for this purpose. However, the plt.matshow() is specifically made for 2D arrays.

In plt.imshow() you have more control over aesthetics such as color mapping and aspect ratios.